# jQuery validation remote

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am having an issue with the jquery validation plugin when checking an email address remote.

The remote function is returning a JSON string like:

```
"{ "isValid": "true", "email": "email@email.com"  }"
```

I know that the default setting in jquery validation should only consist of a json-string returning true or false. But I need to return the email that is checked.

Is it possible to have the remote validation function to check the json-property "isValid"?

Thanks,

James Ford

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily extend the validator plugin. All you have to do is use `$.validator.addMethod()`,  add a method that makes the remote call, gets the JSON string you have shown, performs the tasks for which you need the email address returned and return true or false at the end back to the validation flow.

This might help: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage

Answer (score 4):

To process the response from a custom remote validation call you must create custom rule. In this example we're checking if user nick is available.

jquery validation cutom rule:

```
$('#nick').rules("add", {
  // nick is required
  required: true,
  // nick can have from 3 to 30 characters
  rangelength: [3,30],
  remote: {
    url: "/your-api-url",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      // nick is id of input field from html
      nick: function() {
          // get user input from field value
          return $('#nick').val();
      }
    },
    // custom filtering response from api call
    dataFilter: function(data) {
      // we need to parse data string to json
      var json = JSON.parse(data);
      if(json.nick === "true" || json.nick === true) {
          // jquery validate remote method
          // accepts only "true" value
          // to successfully validate field 
          return '"true"';
      } else {
          // error message, everything that isn't "true"
          // is understood as failure message
          return '"This nick is already taken."';
      }
    }
  }
});
```

response from api if nick is available:

```
{nick:true}
```

html:

```
<input name="nick" id="nick" value="" placeholder="Nick" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could write your custom method using remote() as a source. Something like

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("customRemote", function(value, element, param) {

...
// the piece of code doing AJAX response parsing

success: function(response) {
    validator.settings.messages[element.name].remote = previous.originalMessage;

    // original:
    var valid = response === true || response === "true";

    // replace with your own logic
    if(response.isValid == "true" && something == else) {
        // do the stuff
    }

...

})
```